# xcode multidimensional arrays

Tags: xcode

I need some help with an array that I am working on.

I am pulling back some data from a JSON query and writing it into an array, and then in a second loop I am writing that array into another array but I don't know how to read the data back out??
This is the code:-

```
for (NSDictionary *weather in weatherarray)
{
    int j = 1;
    NSArray *hourlyArray = [weather objectForKey:@"hourly"];
    for (NSDictionary *hourD in hourlyArray)
    {

        [multi addObject:Date];
        [multi addObject:[hourD objectForKey:@"time"]];
        [multi addObject:[hourD objectForKey:@"weatherCode"]];            
        [multi addObject:[hourD objectForKey:@"tempC"]]; 
        [multi addObject:[hourD objectForKey:@"FeelsLikeC"]];            
        [multi addObject:[hourD objectForKey:@"chanceofrain"]];            
        [multi addObject:[hourD objectForKey:@"cloudcover"]]; 
        [multi addObject:[hourD objectForKey:@"WindGustMiles"]]; 
        [multi addObject:[hourD objectForKey:@"humidity"]];             
        [multi addObject:[hourD objectForKey:@"pressure"]]; 
        j = j + 1;
    }     

    [[multi1 objectAtIndex:j] addObject:multi]; 
    i = i + 1;
} 
NSLog(@"%@", [[[multi1 objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1]);
```

}

as you can see I am trying to read the data out at the end in an NSLog but i am struggling, with this. Can anyone help please??

Comment: hmmm, that code gave me a headache I think :) So if I understand this right, you have a map from some weather service, and in there, there's an 'hourly' array that also contains a map with some important weather key/value pairs? And that code is trying to move the data from those maps into some array? That's the part I don't get, what is the point in that?

Comment: sorry if that gave you a headache! Yes, I have a map api service and I am trying to save the data out into some sort of array to write it into a UITable. There is 15 days of data with 12 hours in each day, so what I want to do is loop through the days and write out the hours for each day in the same array so I can write that back to the table. Does that make sense or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define and assign `multi` within the `for` loop. So, put the line

```
NSMutableArray *multi = nil;
```

above the line `[multi addObject:Date]` and move your line

```
[[multi1 objectAtIndex:j] addObject:multi];
```

above the line `j = j + 1;`. You don't need the `i = i + 1;` here, unless you are doing something with it, that is outside the scope of this code fragment.

Unless I have missed something, it should work like that.

Comment: That worked a treat, Thank you so much for your help and understanding my very garbled code! :)